# Is it possible to manually create Envers auditing tables without the revinfo foreign key?

Tags: java, hibernate-envers

In my current project I'm using Envers 5.2.12 to audit an entity changes. Because of security restrictions I must create manually the audit table and revinfo table and they cannot contain a foreign key. If I create them without the foreign key reference will that interfere in Envers normal behaviour?

Comment: I can understand the manual table creation requirement; however, I'm stuck on understanding why you cannot maintain FK relationships between tables of a like schema.  Envers FKs are always between audit tables and never between audit and normal data tables, so I don't grok why that's a problem.

Comment: Hi Naros. It's DBA policy to not include FK's in tables to avoid excesive cpu usage so I must find a workaround. I'm using Envers more like a logging plugin than an auditing one so revinfo is not that important to me. The question is: will envers work if I manually create the tables without the FK's?

Comment: As a former Oracle DBA, that sounds absurd.  If the database is experiencing excessive CPU usage, there has to be a better explanation and to sacrifice a key relational database aspect here is _NOT_ the right approach imo.  I answered your question and do as you must; but understand the risks and potential problems you can face otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer, Envers will work with no foreign keys defined.

**The main caveat here is that this all assumes that the data being maintained remains consistent between related rows as if the Foreign Key was defined.**

In the event that audit data is inserted or deleted from the audit tables that would otherwise normally invalidate a Foreign Key and generate a Constraint Violation exception, all guarantees are voided.

The purpose of a Foreign Key is to guarantee data integrity between related rows.  Without them, you'll never be aware when an operation violates that directive and by the time you notice the problem your data integrity could be so compromised it may be better simply to start from scratch.

While Envers (and generally speak most applications) can operate without FK definitions, you *should* use them as they're literally a corner stone principle in any relational database environment.